# How to select all and reset all the selected marker in leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

```
$.widget("wgm.imgNotes2", $.wgm.imgViewer2, {
    options: {

        addNote: function(data) {
            var map = this.map,
                loc = this.relposToLatLng(data.x, data.y);
            var popup = L.responsivePopup({ hasTip: true, autoPan: false})
                         .setContent(notesArray[data.id]);
            var myicon = L.icon({
                             iconUrl: 'assets/booknow/img/book_pin.png',
                iconSize:     [15, 15], // size of the icon            

                shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
            });
            var newicon = L.icon({
                              iconUrl: 'assets/booknow/img/book_pin_success.png',
                iconSize:     [15, 15], // size of the icon            

                shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
            });

            var highlight = L.icon({iconUrl: 'assets/booknow/img/book_pin.png',
                iconSize:     [45, 45],
            });



            var mark = L.marker(loc, {icon: myicon})
                        .addTo(map).on('click', markerOnClick)
                        .bindTooltip(data.tooltip,{direction: 'top'});
```

How to select all markers in the image in leaflet
and even how to clear all or reset the markers which are selected markers

Comment: Use a `layerGroup`. Add the `layerGroup` to the map, add the markers to the `layerGroup'. You can add and remove the `LayerGroup`.

Comment: is there any option for selecting the marker rather than adding and removing the marker in leaflet